# using an array of boolean values 'expression must have pointer-to-object-type' error C++

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

I'm writing a program to track my workout progress and generate the next workout. I'm using a class to check the last workout and generate the next workout. A function in this class checks the last workout, and if a certain condition is met, adds weight for the next workout.

I would like to use an array of boolean values for this function, with one value per lift type. This way, the lifts can be treated independently as I will undoubtedly make uneven progress.

The function is fairly simple, and I thought it would be no problem, but I am getting the 'expression must have pointer-to-object-type' error when I try to iterate through the array of booleans and set them to true if the condition is met.

Here is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
void setNextWo(bool woProgression, int lastWoLastSetReps[6])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (lastWoLastSetReps[i] >= 5)
        {
            woProgression[i] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The i in woProgression[i] is underlined with the red squiggly and is generating the error. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks very much

**Edit: I just realized I shouldn't be passing the array by reference. I changed this in my code and in the post, but I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: You're passing a reference to a bool variable, not a pointer (which could be interpreted as an array). Edit: Just saw your update, will reanalyze.

Comment: You declare `woProgression` as a simple bool variable, it should be an array instead.

Comment: Beside what was already said: In c++ you should avoid to use c-style arrays. Use `std::array<int,6> lastWoLastSetReps` and `std::array<bool,6> woProgression` instead, and pass those as reference or by pointer into your function.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `woProgression` as a simple bool variable, it should be an array instead.

Posting here identical to my comment to *close* the question and also because I'm not sure OP read the comments.

Comment: Wow I feel like a dummy for overlooking that. Thank you. Also I did read the comments, but I edited before I refreshed to see that you had commented. Anyways, thanks!